# rich text box savefile

Tags: textbox, rtf

While saving a .rtf file from rich text box the file orientation is not preserved, can anyone give me the solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by File orientation?

Comment: File orientation is nothing but the File page setup, A3 get converted to A4 size

Answer (score 0):

Printer settings are not encoded in rtf files (they only describe basic formatting information for the text).